# Replace a string in files with different encodings with Java

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, char

Let's say I have a bunch of files with different encodings and I want to replace massively a string with another one in all of these files.
So for each file I would like to replace that string maintaining unchanged the file encoding.
Is there an easy way for doing it with java, using java.nio.charset or any external library?

Comment: What sorts of encodings are these files in?

Comment: I would like to cope this problem in the most generic way as possible, so the more encodings I can manage the better is

Comment: Is there a way that you mark the encoding of the file? (e.g. file name or some header in the file that is always in the same encoding?) I'm just trying to understand the environment better.

Comment: No I have no header and no name convention, what I'm practically trying to do is to find a string inside files using a grep and then replace the words that matches in the different files with another word.
The files could have any encoding inside the filesystem that I explore.
Thank you, probably I should have added these info in the question.
However if reducing the generality of the solution could help me, I can manage later the exceptions...